# Bean : accessors vs attributes

Tags: java, javabeans, getter-setter

I have always wondered how a bean should **access its *own* attributes**.

Does it have to always use its *getters* and *setters* i.e. `this.getAttribute1()` and `this.setAttribute1()`

or does it have to access it directly with `this.attribute1` when there is no additional processing ?

And what are the best practices when dealing with JPA ?

Comment: I think there wont be much difference in accessing the properties with in the same class. defined with in the same class, attributes can be accessed irrespective of its scope(private, public, protected). When inheritance is applicable, then it matters how to access the parents attributes ? either with getter/ directly with variable.

Comment: Do you mean when using JPA? If so, I'd like to see an answer too; I always use getters and setters just in case, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory it is better to use the getters/setters even inside the class. The reason for this is because you can (initially or later on) add functionality to them (for example lazy loading in a getter).

On the whole it doesn't matter much because you can update local references to getters if you ever update it but it is best practice to simply go for the getter directly unless you have very specific reasons not to do this.

Comment: I read somewhere it was like overkilling when an accessor does nothing more than setting or retrieving the value with a simple this.attribute1.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, we're not required to use the bean's own getters and setters method to access it's attributes since those attributes are visible to the object itself, but I'd suggest you make use of your getters and setters to practice encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

I think there wont be much difference in accessing the properties with in the same class. defined with in the same class, attributes can be accessed irrespective of its scope(private, public, protected). When inheritance is applicable, then it matters how to access the parents attributes ? either with getter/ directly with variable

There is one another case with JPA.

It is always suggested to use getters for the variables while using them with in the same bean class. Especially with Hibernate - JPA combo.

Sample

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    ...........
    X other = (X) obj;
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.getName() != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!name.equals(other.getName()))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Here in the equals, Other instance is also of the same class - still we need to use which is well explained [here](http://blog.xebia.com/2008/03/08/advanced-hibernate-proxy-pitfalls/).

Answer (score 0):

Actually a Bean is a class with no parametric Constructor and attributes provided with getter and setter
e.g

```
public class Bean
{
int x;

 setX(int x)
{
this.x=x;
}

getX()
{
return this.x;
}
```

Now with this bean class when you access the attribute is JSF or JSP it will be like #{bean.x} it means that it is getting the value of the attribute.
THe reason is it will automatically put get and set by itself